# Jquery - Add tags in html with localStorage array value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This code does not work!!

All the code is correct, only the a tag is not added. Why?

I want the values ​​to be displayed after refreshing the page

```js
$('#Search_Id').keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    let key = "Search_Text";
    let value = $(this).val();

    if (key && value) {
      if (localStorage.getItem(key)) {
        let vals = localStorage.getItem(key).split(',');
        if (!vals.includes(value)) {
          vals.push(value);
          vals.sort();
          localStorage.setItem(key, vals.join(','));
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= vals.length - 1; i++) {
          let txt = vals[i];
          $(".search-header .search-result ul.search-result-list li#story_search").append('<a name="search_txt" class="txt-search-story" href="#"><span>' + txt + '</span></a>');
        }
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
      }
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="story_search" class="span-row"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(".search-header .search-result ul.search-result-list li#story_search").append('<a name="search_txt" class="txt-search-story" href="#"><span>' + txt + '</span></a>');` can be written  `$("#story_search").append('<a name="search_txt" class="txt-search-story" href="#"><span>' + txt + '</span></a>');` since IDs need to be unique. If they are not your code will indeed not work more than once

Comment: Please post an example of `vals` - do you get errors messages in the console?

Comment: no, everythings is ok,Displays all values "vals[i]" ​​in Alert

Comment: @mplungjan dosen't display anything in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L876vjmc/46/

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchForm">
  Search: <input id="searchTerm" type="text">
</form>
<ul>
  <li id="searchStory" class="span-row"></li>
</ul>
<button id="clearStory">Clear</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function getItems(key) {
    console.log("Getting Items from key: " + key);
    var results = [];
    try {
      results = localStorage.getItem(key).split(',');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(results);
    return results;
  }

  function setItems(key, data) {
    console.log("Setting Items into key: " + key);
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, data.join(','));
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    }
  }

  function resetItems(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    $("#searchStory").empty();
  }

  function searchItems(key, term) {
    console.log("Search: " + key + ", for: " + term);
    var items = getItems(key);
    if (items.indexOf(term) == -1) {
      console.log("Not Found. Pushing it.");
      items.push(term);
    }
    items.sort();
    console.log(items);
    return items;
  }

  $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let k = "Search_Text";
    let t = $("#searchTerm").val();
    console.log("Trigger Search for: " + t);
    if (k && t != undefined && t.length > 0) {
      if (getItems(k).length == 0) {
        setItems(k, [t]);
      }
      var vals = searchItems(k, t);
      setItems(k, vals);
      $("#searchStory").empty();
      $.each(vals, function(i, s) {
        $("<a>", {
          name: "search_txt",
          class: "txt-search-story",
          href: "#"
        }).html("<span>" + s + "</span>").appendTo($("#searchStory"));
      });
      //location.reload();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#clearStory").click(function() {
    resetItems("Search_Text");
  });
});
```

It can be helpful to setup small functions to help with common operations. I created functions to Get, Save, and Reset the LocalStorage.

Wrapping with a Form is not necessary yet it can be helpful. For example, I use LastPass and this was [causing issues](https://www.rockyourcode.com/assertion-failed-input-argument-is-not-an-htmlinputelement/) when I hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the Input element. Using a Form, the User can enter text and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the form. This also work with Mobile devices when they hit "Go" on the mobile keyboard. It removes an amount of code that is no longer needed.

The rest is just cleaned up jQuery code based on your example.

**Update**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L876vjmc/55/

Now we have `showSearchStory` that can be run by an event or on it's own.

Comment: thanks but after refreshing dosn't display any things

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy it was not clear that you wanted the Search Story to appear when the page loaded. From your example, it was only shown upon Enter was hit.

Comment: You are right, my code is incorrectly. What should I do if I want the page to load?